# How to convert CSV to Parquet in Julia

Tags: csv, julia, parquet

I have a CSV file that I want to convert to Parquet in Julia. I couldn't find anything about it in the forums nor the docs on this conversion. Is such a conversion possible in Julia or do I just simply read the CSV as Parquet? If so? How can I go about doing that?

This is what I have so far.

```
begin
    using Pkg
    Pkg.add("PlutoUI")
    Pkg.add("HTTP")
    Pkg.add("StatsModels")
    Pkg.activate(".")
    import CSV, DataFrames, Dates, StatsPlots, StatsModels
    import DataFrames.DataFrame
    using Plots, PlutoUI, HTTP, DelimitedFiles, Parquet
end

begin
    df = CSV.read("/home/onur/julia-assignment/temp.csv", DataFrame)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Parquet.jl` as in code below:

```
using CSV,DataFrames,Parquet
c = CSV.read(IOBuffer("a;b;c\n1;2.5;a\n2;3.5;b"), DataFrame, delim=";")
Parquet.write_parquet("dat.parquet", c)
```

As for a test let us try to read this back:

```
julia> Parquet.read_parquet("dat.parquet") |> DataFrame
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b         c
     │ Int64?  Float64?  String?
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │      1       2.5  a
   2 │      2       3.5  b
```